# JavaScriptでwindowのサイズ可変を制限するには

Tags: javascript, html, html5

JavaScriptで500pxより下にwindow幅を小さく出来ないようにJavaScriptで制限をかけたいのですが、そのようなAPIは提供されているのでしょうか？
調べてみて、window.minWidthという物が出てきたのですが上手く動作しなかったです。

chromeで動作すれば良いです。
すいませんよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ここでの window とは何を指していますか？

Comment: ブラウザの画面です。

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418306/css-or-javascript-option-to-limit-sizing-browser-window-size

英語版の方法を参考にして記述しておきます。

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  window.resizeTo(1024,800);
});

window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 900 || window.innerHeight < 600) {
        window.resizeTo(1024,800);
    }
};
```

制限はできないのでリサイズイベントをハックしてしまうやり方です。

---

個人的な意見ですが、
ブラウザのウインドウのサイズを制限したり固定してしまったりするやり方はお勧めしません。
固定するなら中のコンテンツ(bodyやcontainer等)の幅や高さを固定すればいいだけです。
windowの幅は基本的にクライアントが自由に変えていいものかと思います。
ちょっと移動したりとか、OSの「ならべて表示機能」や「スナップ機能」を制限する可能性もあります。
またいわゆる迷惑な広告系のサイトで使われる手口です。勝手にブラウザを最大で表示したり
ブラウザの動きを制限して広告より表示しようとするやり方になるので、もしかするとどこかでブラウザ側で対策がされてしまうかもしれないです。

どういう仕様やアプリかはわかりませんが、ウェブサイトであれば、いかなるwindow幅であっても、表示できることを目指したほうがいいと思います。
どうしても固定のwindowで表示したいことであれば、ブラウザの新規windowではなくて、Javascriptを用いたいわゆるポップアップやモーダル表示を利用するべきかと思います。